# Div's tend to collapse when HTML file is moved/uploaded to host.

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I've been working on a website for  my degree, and it was all going swimmingly; until I transferred the index page to my flash drive. When I loaded the page in both IE9 and Chrome, all of the content began to collapse onto itself. I have tried so many things to fix this, but I don't have a clue what to do!?

My site can be found at: **ubermich.co.nf**

CSS is located at: **ubermich.co.nf/style.css**

Can someone please help me, I only have a 4 week deadline and need to get this sorted ASAP...

Thanks in advance,

jordan

Comment: tha path names which you have given inside your website have now been changed , update your path names for all scripts , css , iages etc

Comment: I'm confused, how have the path names been changed? Aren't they relative as opposed to absolute? I'm probably just being stupid,but I'm really not sure what to do. D:

Comment: dont be confused and dont feel stupid , all i meant was that when you developed you website you might have used some static path , just do one thing open the website from flash drive in mozilla , try to debug n see if it says the path is not found or something and then just make a small change over there , correct the path , if it works , bingo

Comment: I don't have Mozilla, the college systems are somewhat limited. Is there any other way I can do this?

Comment: mozilla , chrome these two i have worked on but almost every browser has the bug part , open in chrome , press f12 , work

Comment: I've tried that and still no improvement. This is really stressing me out now.

Comment: what did u try ?? what problems are coming now ???

Comment: I tried to debug the page in both Chrome and Mozilla and I couldn't find any errors. The page is still collapsing upon itself and it only starts to show border radii in Chrome. I thought all of the latest browsers fully supported CSS3?

Comment: hey i am not questioning your debugging skills , but can you please tell if you updated the path for your css files , can you take a screen shot of mozilla fire bug and post

Comment: Paths to your CSS look fine to me. What's not clear though is what the page is supposed to look like. Yes, it does look borked for me in Chrome, and I can see a bunch of CSS rules that I'd change, but can't really suggest what to change them to without knowing what it's supposed to look like.